# Get rid of a postgresql trigger loop

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger that before update on table 'person' executes procedure in which I choose to let or not to let to update the table row values (in which i need to execute update sql call).
It causes the looping in executing trigger 'before update' and executes the procedure once again and so on.

How could I get rid of this?

Comment: Please provide the complete picture including your version of Postgres, relevant table definitions, trigger function and trigger. A common mistake is to re-execute the `UPDATE` in the trigger function instead of just `RETURN NEW`.

Answer (score 0):

Right answer gave Erwin Brandstetter in comment.

My bad was that I use sql call in function, but I needed only make it "return new".

Thank you for the answer.